# Hardware back button closes the app on Tab enabled Ionic 3 app

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When the user hits `my profile` page(or tab), the user is not logged in then it shows `login page` as shown below.On the `login page` where it has `header back button` and it is working fine (you can see the code below).I need the same functionality when the user hits the `hardware back button on Android device`.But it closes the app.Can you tell me how to solve this issue? If you need more info please let me know.

*my-profile.ts*

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public app: App, public userService: UserService
        ) {
        if (!this.userService.userDetails) {
            this.app.getRootNav().setRoot('Login', { profile: true });
            return;
        }
    }
```

*login.ts*

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
        this.profile = this.navParams.data.profile;
    }

    back() {
        if (this.profile) {//not logged in user
            this.navCtrl.setRoot('TabsPage');
        }
    }
```

*login.html*

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons left>
      <button ion-button *ngIf="profile" (click)="back()" tappable><ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>login</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the Platform's `registerBackButtonAction()` method to handle when the user press the native back button.

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-native';
...
constructor(public platform: Platform){

  platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
    if (navCtrl.canGoBack()) { // CHECK IF THE USER IS IN THE ROOT PAGE.
      navCtrl.pop(); // IF IT'S NOT THE ROOT, POP A PAGE.
    } else {
      platform.exitApp(); // IF IT'S THE ROOT, EXIT THE APP.
    }
  });

}
```

But the case here is that you're setting roots and not pushing pages, so this is the normal behaviour of Ionic, when in root page and there's nothing to pop to, the app is closed.

In this case you can do something like this on your login.ts

```
platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
  this.back();
});
```

So every time the user is in the login page and hits the hardware back button it simply call your `back()` method that'll set the root to another page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, friend.It is working perfectly fine :)

Comment: Why not just "push" the login page onto the nav stack, and then the back button can just do a pop (as the hardware back would do by default)? Seems easier than setting roots and overriding buttons to me.

Comment: @rory_za thought about the same, but maybe is the way the app needs to work, like `hey you can use the app all you want, but if you go to see your profile and it's not logged you NEED to log in`, and this way pushing a page is not the best since the user can go back and see the profile page even not logged in, so in this case seting roots is one of the best ways. The other is using modal so he can pass something back to the page if the user wasn't able to log

Comment: Indeed, I would also use a modal, and move the check from `my-profile.ts` above into an ionViewDidEnter, pops up a modal if not logged in the first time, and if you return "unsuccessfully" from the modal it can show a message or something. Then if the user uses the back button they can go back to where they were instead of exiting the app.

Comment: When i am using this , it is saying Property 'back' does not exist on type 'DemoPage'

Answer (score 4):

Just set the property `navExitApp` to `false` in file `app.module.ts` at imports

```
IonicModule.forRoot(YourApp, {
  navExitApp: false
}),
```

Easy! You do not need to touch the registerBackButtonAction event.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a documented option in the [Config](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/config/Config/) object, and it doesn't seem to work for my Ionic 3 app. Where did you find this property?

Comment: This works fine in my case. I also have Ionic 3. Nothing special. I don't know where I found this. Tested on android.

Comment: I can't find this in the public sources of the ionic project on github. Maybe it's magic. :D But I tested it on android. It works like charm.

Comment: @RossRawlins This is not a lie. I dont lie. It works in my case. (Android) :D Indeed it is not official documented.